# How to monitor the Windows Certificate Store

Tags: windows-10, audit

I have a strange phenomenon on some Windows 10 client machines.

I install a root certificate from our enterprise CA on them through a script (none of the clients are domain-joined). Immediately after this installation everything works as expected, the cert is in the machine trusted root store, all is fine.

After some days/weeks this certificate has *somehow* disappeared. I have no idea how, but the cert is gone. Of course I can reinstall it again, but in the meantime the client applications relying on this cert stop working.

So my question is: How do I find out how and when the cert is removed from from the store. I didn't find any obvious audit mechanisms for the store, so the best I could come up with was a scheduled task that runs every few minutes and checks for the certificate but that would give me only a rough timeframe, nothing more.

Do you know any audit/monitoring mechanism I could turn on? Or alternatively any ideas on how I could prevent the cert from getting removed?

Comment: Check the eventlog. I am 99% sure the certificate removal will appear there (Source: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2). If that's the case, set up a trigger on that event.

Comment: @bjoster: I do get an entry in the "CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational" event log when I remove the cert manually via mmc or powershell. There are no relevant entries however in the timeframe where the cert was removed by some unknown mechanism.

Comment: The I'd use the PS path cert:\LocalMachine\AuthRoot  to just copy/monitor the content. You can find a example here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/parallel_universe_-_ms_tech_blog/2015/10/22/export-all-your-trusted-root-certificate-from-local-machine-store/